# humidity level in a basement

Tags: basement

We have a small rec area, metal die cast tractors( about 8 bookshelves and 3 glass cases with a pool table and a concrete floor. What humidity level do I need to set my dehumidifier s on?

Answer (score 1):

Generally between 40 and 60% is considered "ideal" for a controlled humidity environment. But you can set whatever you like; if "mold prevention" is a primary interest, "Below 70%" is suggested by [this document from Florida Solar Energy Center.](http://www.fsec.ucf.edu/en/consumer/buildings/basics/moldgrowth.htm) 60% might well prove more comfortable for people...but it will require more energy input to remove additional water.